# Retrieve Facebook page's messages and sender

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I'm retrieving my page's messages through Graph API calls, but it seems to be impossible to know who sent a message on behalf of my Page. Normally in the Inbox you can know who help manage a page sent a message, and now I'm looking for a way to retrieve that information.

And one more question, at the end of the JSON file that Facebook returns there is an URL to retrieve more data. I wonder if there is any way to automatically take that URL and download the next JSON file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Message` object does not provide this information according to the [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/message/).

Depending on the Framework you are using to work with the Graph API there may be a way to load the next page automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will grant each of the editors an unique number and ask them to include in any messages they send to identify them. I'm using plain cURL to get the JSON, and I don't know much about programming. I'd love to hear your solution to this problem.

Comment: Some guys use their initials to show who answered. But I think there will be a simple solution for the problem.

I work with Java and use RestFB for the Graph API connection. Therefore I can ignore the paging, because the lib handles this.

Comment: I think I'll go with assigning a unique number to each of our editors because then I don't have to worry about duplications. I'm using Python and figuring out some lib that supports GraphAPI. Thanks for the suggestion!